# What is the word prototype used for in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does the prototype in Javascript signify a method that is added to the object? I have been working on object Javascript for a little while and sometimes I see the world prototype.

Maybe a better question would be when is the prototype used in the function. By default I think that all functions have a default prototype property that is what is used in the object. A function is created just like a class in C++ or Java. And then the NEW keyword is used to create the class which is made out of the function.

Code Here:

```
function Sprite(url, pos, size, speed, frames, dir, once) {
        this.pos  = pos;
        this.size = size;
        this.speed  = typeof speed === 'number' ? speed : 0;
        this.frames = frames;
        this._index = 0;
        this.url = url;
        this.dir = dir || 'horizontal';
        this.once = once;
    };

    Sprite.prototype = {
        update: function(dt) {
            this._index += this.speed*dt;
        },
```

Code here:

```
     var pressedKeys = {};
```

This is a simple declaration of an object, correct? I think there are several ways to declare an object in Javascript but this seems to be the most common way.

More Code: In the following code were would the prototype property come to use. I am just not certain why and where the prototype property should be used.

```
<script>
function MyObject1() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
    this.myMeth = function Fart() {
        alert("hello");
    }
}


var a = new MyObject1();
var b = new MyObject1();

document.writeln(a.a);
document.writeln(b.a);
a.myMeth();

</script>
```

Comment: Please refer to this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide Read all of it - it is very helpful

Comment: Do you understand [`prototypal inheritance`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance#the-prototype)?

Comment: No not yet completely. I was reading your page

Comment: Some articles you might want to take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype chain is how you associate a method with a given type instead of just a specific instance of an object.
It's beneficial for performance reasons since you don't have to redefine the method for every instance since it's defined once at the type level.

Example using prototype:

```
var car = function(){
};

car.prototype.start= function(){
};

var myCar = new car();//all car objects will have the start function defined.
```

Example where prototype is not used:

```
var car = {};
car.start = function(){};
```

The biggest difference here is that the second example doesn't take advantage of the prototype, and is instead just tacking on a start method to the current instance only. 
In the first example all created instances will have access to the start method.

Comment: Can you add some example code for this answer if possible. I would like to see a clear explanation.

Comment: Made an update with an example

Comment: So basically the prototype keyword is used to add a function to an object that is not static to the original object. I have done a lot of Java OOP program so I am not new to OOP concepts, but I have not done enough with Javascript to really see the difference. In your opinion what is the best way to create an object in Javascript. I have seen a lot of different ways, but which one is the most common and used the most.

Comment: I prefer the first pattern, but it comes down to personal preference. The prototype offers some performance/memory usage benefits since it enables you to define the objects once. However, IMO it's totally fine to use object initializer as well ({} syntax in second example). Especially for single instance custom objects.

Comment: @Doug: `prototype` is not a *keyword* it's a property that every function has and it has a special meaning. Unlike in Java, where classes are rather "templates", JavaScript objects simply have a reference to another object, their prototype. Whenever you try to access a property on an object and it doesn't exist on the object itself, it is looked up in the prototype chain. Constructor functions is the typical way to create a new object with a specific prototype (the prototype property of the constructor function). Nowadays you can also use `Object.create`.

Comment: Can you show a code example of this? So when I create, say function Foo() { } that is not an object in the terms of Javascript.